# Querying Standard Rendering Elements in CAML

Tags: caml, url, query

Folks I'm looking to use the "standard rendering element" `<PageUrl/>` within a CAML query as per below:

```
 <Or>
    <Eq>
       <FieldRef Name="Webpage" />
       <Value Type="Text">
          <PageUrl />
       </Value>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
       <PageUrl />
       <Value Type="Text">
          // e.g. http://myDiscussionBoardRootUrl
       </Value>
    </Eq>
 </Or>
```

`<PageUrl/>` equals the current webpage that the query is being run in e.g. http://pagequeryrunin.com. The first part of the `<Eq>` query works fine - it compares a field within my list (incidentally it's a discussion board) to the current url in which the query is called in, but the second `<Eq>` fails with a correlation id error.

Is it possible to check if the `<PageUrl/>` equals a predefined string/url?

Thanks folks.

Standard rendering elements:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms439798.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<Or>
    <Eq>
       <FieldRef Name="Webpage" />
       <Value Type="Text">
          <PageUrl />
       </Value>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
       <Value Type="Text">
          <PageUrl />
       </Value>
       <Value Type="Text">
          // e.g. http://myDiscussionBoardRootUrl
       </Value>
    </Eq>
 </Or>
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey but no dice! (I'm still left with a correlation error)